# Input and Output in C++

Tags: c++

I have a difficulty running this C++ code when I type the input into the program the computer spits out "0" instead of the intended output.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int name;
     cout << "Enter your name";
     cin >> name;
     cout << "That name fits you well, " << name;

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Change your datatype from int to string you will get the desired output

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: https://ideone.com/nLiepZ

Comment: I wonder why you use a variable of type  `int` to save a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your name variable from int to string

```
std::string name;
cout << "Enter your name";
cin >> name;
cout << "That name fits you well, " << name;

return 0;
```

Comment: You also have to include the header `<string>`.